# React native - how to set this state with hooks instead of 'this.state'?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Alrighty, I have a Snack Im trying to convert to using functional components / hooks. Am new to the logic of hooks and need some clarity.

Im using this library https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel and setting up the effect like this:

```
this.carouselRef= React.createRef();
    this.state = {
      activeIndex: 0,
      carouselItems: [
        {
          title: 'Item 1',
          text: 'Text 1',
        },
        {
          title: 'Item 2',
          text: 'Text 2',
        },
        {
          title: 'Item 3',
          text: 'Text 3',
        },
        {
          title: 'Item 4',
          text: 'Text 4',
        },
        {
          title: 'Item 5',
          text: 'Text 5',
        },
      ],
    };
  }

  _onPressCarousel = (index) => {
    // here handle carousel press
    this.carouselRef.current.snapToItem(index);
  };

  _renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          this._onPressCarousel(index);
        }}
        style={{
          backgroundColor: 'white',
          borderRadius: 20,
          height: 300,
          padding: 50,
        }}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>{item.title}</Text>
        <Text>{item.text}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };
```

You can view the snack working here https://snack.expo.io/@skyyguy1999/jealous-scone

This was written for the `export default class App` setup, however my app is structured beginning with `export default function App()`

How can I set the above states using hooks? i.e. instead of `this.state =` it would be some syntax like const `carouselState =`

EDIT:

Im now getting error

> prop 'data' is marked as required in 'Carousel' but its value is undefined

with the following modifications:

```
const carouselRef = React.createRef();
  const [carouselState, setCarouselState] = useState({
      activeIndex: 0,
      carouselItems: [
        {
          title: 'Item 1',
          text: 'Text 1',
        },
        {
          title: 'Item 2',
          text: 'Text 2',
        },
        {
          title: 'Item 3',
          text: 'Text 3',
        },
        {
          title: 'Item 4',
          text: 'Text 4',
        },
        {
          title: 'Item 5',
          text: 'Text 5',
        },
      ],
    });

const onPressCarousel = (index) => {
    // here handle carousel press
    carouselRef.current.snapToItem(index);
  };

  const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          onPressCarousel(index);
        }}
        style={{
          backgroundColor: 'white',
          borderRadius: 20,
          height: 300,
          padding: 50,
        }}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>{item.title}</Text>
        <Text>{item.text}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };

<SafeAreaView
                style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'rebeccapurple', paddingTop: 50 }}>
                <View
                  style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                  <Carousel
                    layout={'default'}
                    ref={carouselRef}
                    data={carouselState.carouselItems}
                    sliderWidth={SliderWidth}
                    itemWidth={300}
                    renderItem={renderItem}
                    useScrollView
                    onSnapToItem={(index) => setCarouselState({ activeIndex: index })}
                    activeSlideAlignment="center"
                  />
                </View>
              </SafeAreaView>
```

Comment: By doing that way you are manipulating your main data carouselItems. You should separate them. Check my answer below. @skyguy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example code of yours with hooks implementation,

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  SafeAreaView,
  Dimensions,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';

import Carousel from 'react-native-snap-carousel';

const SliderWidth = Dimensions.get('screen').width;

export default function App() {
  const [activeIndex, setActivateIndex] = useState(0); 
  const [carouselState, setCarouselState] = useState([
        {
          title: 'Item 1',
          text: 'Text 1',
        },
        {
          title: 'Item 2',
          text: 'Text 2',
        },
        {
          title: 'Item 3',
          text: 'Text 3',
        },
        {
          title: 'Item 4',
          text: 'Text 4',
        },
        {
          title: 'Item 5',
          text: 'Text 5',
        },
      ],
    );

  const _onPressCarousel = (index) => {
    // here handle carousel press
    this.carouselRef.current.snapToItem(index);
  };

  const _renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          this._onPressCarousel(index);
        }}
        style={{
          backgroundColor: 'white',
          borderRadius: 20,
          height: 300,
          padding: 50,
        }}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>{item.title}</Text>
        <Text>{item.text}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView
      style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'rebeccapurple', paddingTop: 50 }}>
      <View
        style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Carousel
          layout={'default'}
          ref={this.carouselRef}
          data={carouselState}
          sliderWidth={SliderWidth}
          itemWidth={300}
          renderItem={this._renderItem}
          useScrollView
          onSnapToItem={(index) => setActivateIndex(index)}
          activeSlideAlignment="center"
        />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
  
}
```

You don't have to declare all your state variables into one declaration. You can separate them into pieces and use&manipulate separately.

hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [useState hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html), for example

```
const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);
```

Comment: Right, but how do I do this with something like the this.state example which is a dictionary/has multiple properties?